# How to write data of a single dimensional array to the next column in a file using Fortran 90?

Tags: arrays, file, fortran, format, output

Basically, I have many single dimensional arrays that I need to write to the same file, but I need to have each array in a separate column, one after the other in the order specified. I would use a "do" loop, but some of the arrays may have more values than the other. Is there a format that I can use in the write statement that will start at the next column instead of continuing after the previous one?

Comment: Welcome, please show us your code and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Can you show, please:1) how are those arrays declared? 2) a sample of the output file you want and how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a 'write' statement that will figure out whether the value it is writing is beyond upper limit of the array or not and then write a blank if the upper limit is crossed. A format can not handle such investigations. I am doubtful whether there is a shortcut command to what you require. One of the way to do is convert the array into array of characters and where you are going beyond scope of your number array, just leave it blank. Below is the implementation of this idea.

```
module sub

contains

subroutine tovalue(num_array,dim,value_array)

implicit none
real*8,intent(in)::num_array(:)
integer,intent(in)::dim

character,intent(inout)::value_array*(*)(:,:)

integer::i,n

n = size(value_array,2)

do i=1,n
    if (i<size(num_array)) then
        write(value_array(dim,i),"(F6.1)") num_array(i)
    else
        write(value_array(dim,i),"(6X)")
    end if
end do

end subroutine

end module
```

This subroutine can be used in the following way:

```
program test
use sub
implicit none
real*8::A(10),B(12),C(15)
integer::i,n

character,allocatable::values*6(:,:)

A = (/2,1,4,1,2,4,5,7,4,9/)
B = (/5,7,4,1,5,5,4,9,6,2,1,5/)
C = (/2,4,7,5,9,6,3,2,1,4,5,8,7,4,5/)

n = MAX(size(A),size(B),size(C))
allocate(values(3,n))

call tovalue(A,1,values)
call tovalue(B,2,values)
call tovalue(C,3,values)

print"(3A6)", values(:,1:n)

end program
```